# How is this for-loop working?

Tags: c++

I am new to programming and whenever I have used a for loop it has consisted of the following

```
 1. Initialize
 2. Condition 
 3. Body 
 4. Update 
 5. Go to 2
 6. Quit.
```

However  in the for loop before what is `cin>>number` doing in place of the update?

```
int number = 0;
cout<<"please enter a number that is greater than 15"<<endl;
for (cin>>number; number <= 15; cin>>number)
{
    cout<<" Please enter a number that is greater than 15"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Read this before asking http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: Er, guys, why all the downvotes?

Comment: It's a bit simplistic but I don't think it's *that* unreasonable a question. I've certainly seen worse.

Comment: "cin" reads input from the keyboard.  The for loop is designed to keep looping until the user enters a number > 15

Comment: It is an update, just reading the new value from the console. Very unusual though.

Comment: @ubercooluk Care to elaborate on why you don't think this meets the criteria in the FAQ? Seems like a perfectly valid question to me.

Answer (score 5):

1. **Initialize**

   cin>>number

   User is asked to provide the initial value.
2. **Condition**

   number<=15

   Number is checked against condition.

   If number is less than 15, go to 3, else go to 6.
3. **Body**

   cout<<" Please enter a number that is greater than 15"<< endl;

   This forms the body, which is executed every time.
4. **Update**

   cin>>number

   User is again asked to input a number.
5. **Go to 2**
6. **Quit**

---

Also, this a very odd coding style. Looping constructs are usually not used in this form. They have the elements that you mentioned but in a more clearer way.

If your reference has code like this, you should probably refer to something else. Its probably not the best book to begin studying C++ with. See some of the books [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 4):

It is a wierd style, but essentially it prompts the user for a number each iteration (instead of  the typical initialization or loop counter update steps ) and checks that against 15. **As long as user enters < 15, it keeps looping**.

This is not how I would write it if readability is high on my priority list (it should be #1 or close). This kind of code might be better expressed as.

```
cin>>number;
while (number <= 15){
    cout<<" Please enter a number that is greater than 15"<<endl;
    cin>>number;
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer, but you should probably mention that code like this is not recommended; as it's non-idiomatic, and therefore confusing!

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I thought I covered that in "It is a wierd style"

Comment: @Oli: I don't think using for loops "non-idiomatically" should be avoided because it's "confusing", although the fact that `cin>>number` is duplicated here is a bit ugly. Would you also ban for loops that, say, navigate tree structures because they don't have a familiar `int i`?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen: Well the ugly duplication is one thing, but also the fact that stuff with complex side effects is hidden inside the for construct.  This could be handled idiomatically with a do-while loop or something, and therefore should be avoided, IMO.  Obviously, it's a style thing, though...

Answer (score 1):

The update stage is the 2nd `cin >> number` in the for statement.

This is a somewhat unusual way of doing this, but it is a perfectly valid update of number. Although ++ and -- are somewhat more common, this clearly does the job of updating number each time round the loop. People often go to quite an amount of effort to avoid having the initialisation part the same as the update part, though I'm not sure why.

Answer (score -1):

"cin>>number" accepts the number
"number <= 15"  checks ths condition is number is greater or equal to 15
then again